# AWS Connecting to Postgres Not Working

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I am very new to AWS/Elastic Beanstalk/RDS but I can't figure out why I am unable to connect to my Postgres DB via Postico.

As far as I can tell, I am entering the correct credentials found under "Environment Properties" in the AWS dashboard.

When I run `psql` statements from the terminal (ssh'd in here as "ec2-user@ip-*****") it says "command not found". But my site is actually up and working. And according to the RDS tab on AWS it is definitely using Postgres.

When I try and connect using Postico (not via SSH), it just hangs for ages and then times out. No error! I'm using the same user, password, and host names stored in the "Environment Properties". I'm even using port 5432.

What can I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to the RDS Dashboard
2. select 'DB Instances'
3. click the toggle in the LH column under "filter" next to database you wish to attach to
4. Copy the "Endpoint" setting ie  postgres-db.ba2syxhcyfxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5678
5. on your EC2 shell as root issue command `yum install postgresql`
6. in your shell on an EC2 issue command `psql -h  postgres-db.ba2syxhcyfxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5678 -U myuser`

Where "myuser" is the user you wish to attach as

Comment: added step to answer for installing postgresql client software.  Hopefully yum is set up...

Comment: If you receive errors like: `No match for argument: postgresql10` or `No match for argument: postgresql14` while running `sudo yum install -y postgresql<your_version>`. Just check what versions persist in repositories using `sudo yum search "postgres"`. In my case there were neither postgresql10 nor postgresql14, but was postgresql15. So I invoked `sudo yum install postgresql15` and it worked.

Comment: @HereAndBeyond yes, and the same thing applies for postgresql clients on Ubuntu